# How to get hobbies in student lists with subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

well, i have 100 student lists and every student has more than a hooby.

i have 2 tables,

table name = students
attribute = student_id,name,dob,address

and

table name = hobbies
attribute = hobby_id, student_id, hoby_name.

how do i get result like below.

```
.student_id | name   | dob        | address   | hobby.
 1          | Jordan | 12-12-1998 | 23 avenue |reading, dota2, football
 2          | Bela   | 13-01-1997 | 12 hills  |swimming, badminton
 3          | Jack   | 01-02-1999 | 07 clinton|dota2
```

once i try to use subquery it says "subquery returns more than 1 row".

thank u guys.

Comment: please give me your query?

Answer (score 1):

```
select sa.student_id,name,dob,address, GROUP_CONCAT(hoby_name)
from students_attribute sa
left join hobbies_attribute ha
on sa.student_id = ha.student_id
group by sa.student_id
```

This will provide to required result.